# How to get default email account information in android..?

Tags: android, email

I am developing an application which requires to auto populate a
default email field.
The logical choice is to retrieve the email address from the email
client provided by android.
I searched the content providers and did not find anything about the
email client.
How is this information stored?
How can I reach it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
AccountManager accManager = AccountManager.get(context);
Account acc[] = accManager.getAccounts();
int accCount = acc.length;
AppConstants.accOnDevice = new Vector<String>();
for(int i = 0; i < accCount; i++){
//Do your task here...
}
```

Permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
```

Comment: hi i fallow the above code it's working good.If don't please give info about, how to get  sent and received info details.If u know please help me.

Comment: sorry, this info is not provided.

Comment: you have to use OAuth integration for further access.you can look at following link: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/MobileApps

Comment: Hi, this method gives all the available accounts. In case the user has more than one you might not be able to determine which is the principal account.